# Openssl commends does not run in cmd

Tags: cmd, openssl

I am following a tutorial where they run openssl commend.
I am trying to run openssl command

```
openssl s_client -connect ldap.domain.com:454 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -out certfile.txt
```

But it does not work in window cmd, I get this error message

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

I don't understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path /dev/null is a unix-path. It doesn't exist on windows systems.